# Getting certified at Dreamforce

Tags: discussion, dreamforce, certification

I will be attending dreamforce this time and I would like to take the DEV401 certification exam. I know it will be held on Monday Nov 17 at 7:30 am. But I am not sure how I can register for this.

I found this page mentioning where the exams will be held at. 
http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF13/training.jsp

Can someone please tell me how?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this question posed in Meta rather than in the main site?

Comment: ^^ I posted it here since I the rest of the Dreamforce related questions are also in this section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Monday AM exams are fully booked. They are offering "drop-in" exams by advance registration at the Dreamforce rate on Tuesday & Wednesday at the Salesforce office at 50 Fremont Street. Full details in [this Chatter post](https://dreamevent.my.salesforce.com/0D53000001JlYDK) in the Dreamforce org, and the form to express interest is at http://bit.ly/examdrop-in

Comment: Thanks so much Thomas. I did register at the link you provided. I hope I get to take the exam. BTW do you know if we need a web assessor account in order to take the exam? Thanks!

Comment: For the Monday exams, my understanding is that they are creating WebAssessor accounts for new users. I would ask whomever responds to your form submission to make sure.